# Explain the example with a callback (fat arrow function) as a function argument

Tags: javascript, arrays, filter, ecmascript-6, arrow-functions

I'm doing the Udemy course `ES6 Javascript: The Complete Developer's Guide
Stephen Grider` on my own. Most of the first 4 sections were too easy so I've been doing all the exercises with fat arrow functions (which are new to me and not covered so far in the course) to make it more interesting.

However, when I got to `Coding Exercise 8: Challenging! Implementing 'reject'`,  I could not figure out how to do it with fat arrow functions.

The challenge is to create a function called 'reject' that works in the opposite way to `Array.filter`. Conceptually, that's easy - just use `!`.

Being stumped, I found a proposed solution using fat arrow functions that works. Here it is:

```
const numbers = [10, 20, 30];

function reject(array, iteratorFunction) {
    return array.filter(arrItem => !iteratorFunction(arrItem))

}
reject(numbers, num => num > 15);
```

I do not understand it. Can someone explain what's going on here? Also, is there a better implementation using fat arrow functions?

Comment: What exactly *don’t* you understand?

Comment: You are passing to reject as second argument an abstract function "num=>num < 15"  so this "!iteratorFunction(arrItem))" is calling it

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To understand the example one needs familiarity and usage of callback functions, anonymous functions, and arrow syntax.

Consider the code:

```
function reject(array, iteratorFunction) {
    return array.filter(arrItem => !iteratorFunction(arrItem));
}
```

The definition of Array `filter`: The `filter()` method creates a new array with all elements that pass the test implemented by the provided callback function.

*What is a callback function?* A callback function is a function passed into another function as an argument, which is then invoked inside the outer function to complete some kind of routine or action. This invoking happens when the function with its body (code) is actually passed during invocation.

The following code is a callback function: `arrItem => !iteratorFunction(arrItem)`
The function returns a boolean. The function is written as arrow syntax.

This can also be written as:

```
function(arrItem) {
    return !iteratorFunction(arrItem);
}
```

`iteratorFunction` is also a callback function, which returns a boolean. The '!' operator makes the returned boolean negated (turns true to false and vice-versa).

So, the following `reject` function code works similarly:

```
function reject(array, iteratorFunction) {
    return array.filter(function(arrItem) {
                            return !iteratorFunction(arrItem);
    });
}
```

-the following is same as above-

```
function reject(array, iteratorFunction) {

    let myCallback = function(arrItem) {
                         return !iteratorFunction(arrItem);
                     };

    return array.filter(myCallback);
}
```

**iteratorFunction is callback function**

In the example, consider this code: `num => num > 15`

The code is an arrow syntax of a callback function. This can also be written as:

```
function(num) {
    return num > 15;
}
```

That means the code:

```
let result = reject(numbers, num => num > 15);
```

-can also be written as-

```
let result = reject(numbers, function(num) {return num > 15});
```

-can also be written as-

```
let myCallback = function(num) {
    return num > 15;
}

let result = reject(numbers, myCallback);
```

The result is: `[ 10 ]`

Answer (score 1):

num => num > 15 translates to the following anonymous function

```
function(num){
  return num > 15
}
```

If you have only one argument, you don't need to provide round brackets and if you are returning an expression , you can skip the curly braces and writing "return"

Once , the function syntax is clear,then it is just about passing the function as an argument to reject and providing values of the array as the argument to the anonymous function.